# Display as a row unless it would overflow the container in which case display as a column?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Pretty straightforward question. I have a react-native app. I have a container with three elements in (a string, a graph and a number). I want those elements to display as a row, unless it would spill over the edge of the screen in which case I want it to display as a column. The reason for this is that the row looks better, but due to internationalisation, the string in question could potentially get quite long, in which case the rest of the contents of the container are pushed off the screen which obviously looks bad and isn't user friendly. If this is the case I'd prefer it to format as a column as then the user could simply scroll down and view the full information.

This is the current styling:

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  flexShrink: 1,
  flexDirection: "row",
  alignContent: "space-between",
  alignItems: "center",
  backgroundColor: "white",
  margin: "1rem",
  marginTop: "0.2rem",
  marginBottom: "0.2rem",
  justifyContent: "space-evenly"
  },
```

Simply removing flexDirection: row causes it to display as a column which I'd prefer not to be the default case.

Comment: Have you tried `flex-wrap: wrap;`?

Comment: Yes, it just causes it to default display as a column. I know that (at least in French) the string is short enough that it can fit into a row without issues so I'm not sure why flex-rap isn't working

Comment: You need to set the width of `.container` to make it work. It is needed to set the width of `.container` to fit on parent.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way to specify the width of a container without actually changing the width of what I see in the emulator?

Comment: I need more info for that. The width of `.container` should be same as the emulator width?